# Is python.exe.manifest the right way to make pywinauto access metro style app in win8?

Tags: microsoft-metro, python-2.6, pywinauto

I'm trying to enumerate and automate metro style app in Windows 8.1 using pywinauto in Python 2.6.
If I use inspect.exe from Windows Kit to obtain the HWND and then pass it to pywinauto.handleprops.process_id(), I am able to get the correct process id.

However, if I use pywinauto.findwindows.enum_windows(), I don't see the specific HWND that inspect.exe being listed there.  I suspect that the reason could have something to do with UAC/UIPI, since c:\python26\python.exe doesn't have a manifest.  Am I correct?

I try to work around by putting the below python.exe.manifest and pythonw.exe.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation -->
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    name="*.*.*"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    version="1.0.0.0"
    type="win32"/>
  <description>*</description>
  <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <security>
          <requestedPrivileges>
              <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="true"/>
          </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

But it doesn't seem to help.  I don't even think UAC elevation happen, since no UAC prompt appear.  Anyway, inspect.exe.manifest on uses `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>`

Does anybody have a better suggestion how should i go about?

Comment: I am sure UAC & manifest do not affect windows enum. Anyway, I am recomending you to use the next construction to get windows list. handles = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(top_level_only=False, visible_only=False). Also you can use the GUI tool for pywinauto, it is like inspect, but is tuned for pywinauto module

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick.
First I get all the handles like what you suggested:
>>> handles = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(top_level_only=False, visible_only=False)

Then I use inspect.exe to obtain the "Native Window Handle" of "Music", which is 0x3025C which is decimal 197212.
It seems that it is not in the list of handles:
>>> 197212 in handles
False

I then verify if 197212 is indeed the handle of "Music" by getting its pid.
>>> hndp = pywinauto.handleprops
>>> hndp.processid(197212)
1768

Finally I use taskmgr to verify that the pid is "Music", which is WWAHost.exe.

Comment: Apparently EnumWindows doesn't work with Metro, looks like pywinauto needs to upgrade somehow. http://wj32.org/wp/2012/12/12/enumwindows-no-longer-finds-metromodern-ui-windows-a-workaround-2/

Comment: Agree with user1380947

Comment: Actually, just out of curiosity, why is is pywinauto using win32api like EnumWindows and not using the UIAutomation api instead?

Comment: Good question, @user1380947. UIAutomation has some difficulties in the use from python, pywinauto's developer does not spend a lot of time for project development. Perhaps someone ;-) will find the same time and finish the library, similar to pywinauto but based on UIAutomation.

Comment: Now we have a pywinauto prototype working with UI Automation API, but still need to finalize some architecture changes.